What feature extractor paramters to use with SIFT for very simple symbol detection
enter image description hereI need to detect symbols on a drawing. I want to use following procedure:

feature extraction on each symbol in the trainingset using SIFT
feature extraction on the scene image
compare if the symbol is detected and check rotation , scale, etc.

I got this to work with pretty statisfing result. However, some of my symbols are so simple that SIFT is unable to extract features. (i use open cv 4.10.0)
I don't really understand, because the symbol does have some distinctive edges and corners.
The symbol looks like this:
enter image description here
I tried increasing the nFeatures parameter, change the grayscale to binary for more contrast, but no improvement.
Are there settings for the detector that i can change so multiple features are detected? Or perhaps some preprocessing on the symbol i can try?
the code I use to detect the features: (nfeatures is set to 500)
    def getFeatures(self,img_object):   
    #step1 extract features using SIFT on all img_objescts
    keypoints_obj = []
    descriptors_obj = []

    if (self.type=="SIFT"):
        detector = cv.SIFT_create(nfeatures=self.nfeatures)
        keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = detector.detectAndCompute(img_object, None)

    return keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj  

If i run this on an icon, i get following results:
6 KP detected for a single line symbol (vectorized)
and
127 keypoints detected for a enhanced, not vectorized symbol
how can i enhance the results on vectorized symbols?

Please share a minimal reproducible example including code and sample images!
